# Change coordinates of raster file

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I'm trying to compute zonal statistics but get an error saying that "negative dimensions are not allowed". I'm assuming its because my raster file extends into negative coordinates. Extent of the file is xmin: 0, xmax: 21600, ymin: -8700, ymax: 0. (The top left corner of the image is 0, 0). I want to move this up so that ymin: 0 and ymax: 8700. Alternatively, if there is another way to avoid this error that is welcome.
[image]

Comment: What format is the raster? You could create a world file for most formats which would be recognized by most GIS software assuming you know the origin and cell size. http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/General/topics/author_world_files.htm

Comment: Does it have a defined coordinate reference system? If it's set to a geographic coordinate system, QGIS may be smart enough to see that the coordinates don't match. Right now, this raster is not georeferenced.

Comment: Resolved by just downloading original raster from data source which had normal coordinates. For some reason in the file I was provided coordinates corresponded to pixels in the raster.